# 7 wire outlet to 6

Tags: receptacle

I think I wired my outlet wrong.

I have 7 wires coming out of the wall, 2 red, 2 black 2 white and a ground. I only have 4 holes on the back of my new outlet so I put both red wires under 1 screw and both black wires under 1 screw then each white on their own and the ground to the green screw.

When I used the tester everything was green so I closed it up but now I'm a little worried. Is this okay,

[image]

Comment: Where you replacing an existing outlet?   If so how was it wired?   I sounds like you have provisions for switched outlets.   Do you have a wall switch that controls the outlet? If so (and you are replacing an outlet), and you wish to have one switched and the other hot, you need to break off the little tab on the HOT side, put the reds together on one screw on the hot side and the blacks together on the other HOT side screw. The neutrals go to the other side and don't break off the tab if there is on.

Comment: Where on the planet are you?

Comment: Do you have conduit or cables? If conduit, how are the wires grouped? If cables, do you have two cables, each with black, red, and white wires?

Comment: Do you have any idea where those wires go? Do you want advice about how to find out?

Comment: Yes I was replacing an older outlet. There is no wall switch for this outlet.

Comment: Can you tell us how the old outlet was connected?   This might be part of a multi-wire-branch-circuit (MWBC).   Have you powered it up? This is an odd configuration.   Again, tell us where in the world you are.  Local customs and codes vary a lot.

Comment: Washington state,  house is from 1995. Any way to send a picture?

Comment: What kind of tester did you use?

Comment: Did you switch off only one breaker to shut off the power to all the wires in the box?

Comment: Can you shoot us a photo of the old receptacle, the side with the brass screws?  We're looking for a little metal tab connecting them (or absent).

Comment: @BrianGephart -- [edit] your post and then use the "mountain and sun" button on the editor toolbar to add your photo

Comment: Do you have photos showing the hot side of the outlet?

Comment: Just a suggestion get some wire nuts and pigtail those wires so only 1 hot and 1 neutral is going to the receptacle. It will save you from coming back when it quits working.